# docker-compose.yml not found - error on build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a new VM with ubuntu 22.04 and asked to install docker

When I create a docker-compose file and having to run the build, the following errors occur:

```
pilati@ubuntu-web-containers:/var/www/mysql$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 out  1 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 out  1 16:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  473 out  1 16:42 docker-compose.yml
pilati@ubuntu-web-containers:/var/www/mysql$ sudo docker-compose build
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml

pilati@ubuntu-web-containers:/var/www/mysql$ sudo docker-compose -f /var/www/mysql/docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/mysql/docker-compose.yml'
pilati@ubuntu-web-containers:/var/www/mysql$
```

I reinstalled the VM from scratch and nothing works.

Any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your compose to your home folder, it should work from there. That is because you installed docker with snap, install it as is from the [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) site.

Comment: reinstalling solved the problem